# Sequence to Communication diagrams

Tags: uml, diagram, sequence-diagram

I have made a `sequence diagram` in `UML`,
and since there is similarity with the `communication diagram`
for the same project,

is there a program that could `convert`
the sequence diagram to a communication diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are few tools with Eclipse but no open source.

Comment: I use this feature within EclipseUML Omondo